# Load a div with onload function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 different div which shows particular content in each other. But now i want to show content of my first div when the page loads itself. in reference with code below when my page loads it should show the content of LTE .

```
<div id="lte" class="content_main">
    <h1> lte</h1>
</div>

<div id="device_details" class="content_main">
    <h1> device details</h1>
</div>


<div id="self_care" class="content_main">
    <h1>selfcare</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean you want the other divs to be hidden?

Comment: Are you looking at implementing something like a tabbed structure?

Comment: This will happen already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#device_details").hide();
    $("#self_care").hide();
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Somnath_k/LtWWm/)

Comment: thanks working...
but this would be more appropriate..Thanks anyways


     $(document).ready(function(){$("#LTE").show();});

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){$("#LTE").show();}) this wwill not hide the other two divs .If u want this u have to hide the other two divs with css

Answer (score 1):

Just hide the other elements with CSS:

```
#device_details, 
#self_care {
  display:none;
}
```

Then to show in the future use display:block; or with jQuery:

```
$('#device_details', '#self_care')show();
```

Answer (score 0):

try out this..

```
<div id="lte" class="content_main">
    <h1> lte</h1>
</div>

<div id="device_details" class="content_main" style="display:none;">
    <h1> device details</h1>
</div>


<div id="self_care" class="content_main" style="display:none;">
    <h1>selfcare</h1>
</div>
```

or you can do javascrip code like this..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#device_details").hide();
    $("#self_care").hide();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use CSS not JavaScript.

```
.content_main {
  display: none;
}
.content_main:first-child {
  display: block;
}
```